# WebSQL data into AngularJs DropDown

Tags: angularjs, web-sql, jaydata

I have very simple question about getting data from `WebSql`
I have `DropDown` i.e

```
<select id="selectCatagoryFood" data-role="listview" data-native-menu="true"
                ng-init="foodCatagory = foodCatagories.cast[0]"
                ng-options="foodCatagory as foodCatagory.text for foodCatagory in foodCatagories.cast"
                ng-model="foodCatagory"
                ng-change="changeFoodCatagory()">
                </select>
```

now i want to add data init from `webSQL`. I already get Data from `webSql` but i am confuse that how to add that data into `DropDown`
An example or hints maybe very helpful for me.

**Update 1 :: Add Controller Code**

```
myApp.controller('foodSelection',function($scope,foodCatagories){
$scope.foodCatagories = foodCatagories;
$scope.changeFoodCatagory = function(){
    alert($scope.foodCatagory.value);
}
});
```

**Update 2 `webSQL` and `JayData`**

```
_context.onReady({
    success: showData,
    error: function (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});

function showData(){
    var option = '';
    _context.FoodGroup.forEach(function(FG)
    {
        option += '<option value="'+FG.FoodGroupID+'">'+FG.Description+'</option>';
    }).then(function(){
        console.log(option);
    });
}
```

**Update 3**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('foodCatagories',function(){
     var foodCatagories = {};
     foodCatagories.cast = [
     {
         value: "000",
         text: "Select Any"
    }
    ];
return foodCatagories;
});
```

**Update 4**
One thing that i didn't mention is that I am using `JayData` for getting data from `webSQL` to my App

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @RoyTruelove i updated my question with controller code

Comment: Add your code for getting data via webSQL plz

Comment: In your controller code foodCategories is a service or something, can you add its code to the question as well.

Comment: @vittore Question Updated add the code of `foodCategories` as well as getting data from webSql code

Comment: anybody have any idea about it?
@RoyTruelove Vittore

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain how it works:

**EDIT**: [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/AxExIgi/2/edit?html,js,output)

**html**

Here is your stripped down select.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.text for item in foodCategories"
        ng-model="foodCategory"
        ng-required="true"
        ng-change="changeFoodCategory()">
</select>
```

The directive `ng-options` will fill automatically the `option` elements in your select. It will take the `foodCategories` variable from the `$scope` of your controller and foreach `item` in the collection, it will use the `text` property as the label shown (`<option>{{item.text}}</option>') and it will select the whole object`item`as the value of the selected`option`. You could also refer to a property as the value like (`{{item.text}}`). Then your`ng-model`would be set to the`id` value of the selected option.

The directive `ng-model` corresponds to the variable in the `$scope` of your controller that will hold the value of the selected option.

The directive `ng-required` allows you to check if a value has been selected. If you are using a form, you can check if the field is valid `formName.ngModelName.$valid`. See the docs for more details on form validation.

The directive `ng-change` allows you to execute a function whenever the selected option changes. You may want to pass the `ng-model` variable to this function as a parameter or call the variable through the `$scope` inside the controller.

If no default value is set, angular will add an empty option which will be removed when an option is selected.

You did use the `ng-init` directive to select the first option, but know that you could set the `ng-model` variable in your controller to the default value you would like or none.

**js**

Here I tried to simulate your database service by returning a promise in the case that you are doing an async request. I used the `$q` service to create a promise and `$timeout` to fake a call to the database.

```
myApp.factory('DbFoodCategories', function($q, $timeout) {
    var foodCategories = [
        { id: 1, text: "Veggies", value: 100 },
        { id: 2, text: "Fruits", value: 50 },
        { id: 3, text: "Pasta", value: 200 },
        { id: 4, text: "Cereals", value: 250 },
        { id: 5, text: "Milk", value: 150 }
    ];

    return {
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Your call to the database in place of the $timeout
            $timeout(function() {
                var chance = Math.random() > 0.25;
                if (chance) {
                    // if the call is successfull, return data to controller
                    deferred.resolve(foodCategories); 
                }
                else {
                    // if the call failed, return an error message
                    deferred.reject("Error"); 
                }
            }, 500);

            /*  // your code
            _context.onReady({
                success: function() {
                     deferred.resolve(_contect.FoodGroup); 
                },
                error: function (error){
                     deferred.reject("Error"); 
                }
            });
            */

            // return a promise that we will send a result soon back to the controller, but not now
            return deferred.promise; 
        },
        insert: function(item) {
            /* ... */
        },
        update: function(item) {
            /* ... */
        },
        remove: function(item) {
            /* ... */
        }
    };
});
```

In your controller you set the variables that will be used in your view. So you can call your `DbFoodCategories` service to load the data into `$scope.foodCategories`, and set a default value in `$scope.foodCategory` that will be used to set the selected option.

```
myApp.controller('FoodSelection',function($scope, DbFoodCategories){
    DbFoodCategories.get().then(
        // the callback if the request was successfull
        function (response) {
             $scope.foodCategories = response; //response is the data we sent from the service
        },
        // the callback if an error occured
        function (response) {
             // response is the error message we set in the service
             // do something like display the message
        }
    );

    // $scope.foodCategory = defaultValue;

    $scope.changeFoodCategory = function() {
        alert($scope.foodCatagory.value);
    }
});
```

I hope that this helped you understand more in detail what is happening!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the down votes after 6 months? This answer explains in details what you needed to do with your webSql+JayData.

Comment: i didn't down or up vote. Anyways i used that `toLiveArray();` after new release.

Answer (score 0):

in the new version we released a new module to support AngularJS. We've started to document how to use it, you can find the first blogpost [here](http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-and-angularjs)
With this you should be able to create your dropdown easily, no need to create the options manually. Something like this should do the trick:

```
myApp.controller('foodSelection',function($scope, $data) {
   $scope.foodCatagories = [];
   ...
   _context.onReady()
   .then(function() {
      $scope.foodCatagories = _context.FoodGroup.toLiveArray();
   });
});
```

provided that FoodGroup has the right fields, of course

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](http://jaydata.org/blog/angularjs-with-jaydata%E2%80%93-the-todo-example-with-the-itemstore-api) and how use $apply to update the data in scope.

Comment: please do not use it, it's obsoleted....  the new module is documented in our blog